# A vector/vertex but with integer values

Tags: c++, qt, std

I need something like [QVector3D](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector3d.html) type but with integer values.

It means, rather than:

```cpp
QVector3D(float xpos, float ypos, float zpos)
```

I need:

```cpp
QVector3i(int first, int second, int third)
```

Does Qt have such a type? If not, what would be the best workaround?

Comment: _If not, what would be the best workaround?_ `struct QVector3i { int x, y, z; };`? (You could provide a bit more context for a serious answer.)

Comment: why does it have to be a `QVector3X` ? Can you not use a `std::array<int,3>` ? `QVector` has some convenience methods, though for most of them you need to consider if they are fine with integers anyhow. For example for lenght you might want a manhattan distance instead to stay with integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @idclev463035818 suggestion, `std::array<int, 3>` does the job for me.